# Is there a torch in every episode of Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

Something I have been noticing since I started watching Doctor Who for the first time over the last few months.

Is there a torch in every episode? Is that significant? And by torch I mean either a literal torch with fire, or a flashlight/electric torch.

For those who don't know, in England both items are known as torches.

Comment: Would it have something to do with Torchwood?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris, it could. But I've seen this going back all the way to the first episodes in '63.

Comment: I've never watched Dr Who. I just know that Torchwood is a spin off lol.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: I kinda have been hoping that the name Torchwood was in recognition of this fact of the show. But I haven't seen anything about it online.

Comment: As far as I know Torchwood is merely an anagram of Doctor Who.

Comment: Also, Torchwood is an anagrams of Doctor Who.

Comment: The episodes seem to be getting darker - and I don't mean scarier/grimmer, I mean the lighting budget seems to have been cut! (To pay for more special effects?) Also scenes set in areas with only emergency lighting. Maybe the torches are the actors trying to see each other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just a few episodes that I'm 90% certain are "torch free":

- *The Leisure Hive* (Tom Baker)
- *Logopolis* (Tom Baker)
- *Castrovalva* (Peter Davidson)

and jumping ahead a bit

- *The End of the World* (Christopher Eccleston)
- *The Lodger* (Matt Smith)

Torches (both kind) are certainly popular, as lighting adds to the suspense, but no.

The Torchwood reference stems from *Tooth and Claw* (David Tenant) in which Rose and the 10th Doctor encounter werewolves while staying at the Torchwood Estate.  The Torchwood Institute is later founded by Queen Victoria to defend the Empire against the Alien Menace (including The Doctor).

Comment: *The Sontaran Experiment* was pretty much all outside in daylight.

Comment: Oh very good!  Had forgotten that one.

Answer (score 2):

All the episodes of the female Doctor Who, Thirteenth Doctor, (so far) have been torch free.

Comment: Which might explain the declining audiences. All those torch fans turning off.